What is the difference between multipart/mixed, multipart/related and multipart/alternative?
Email headers specify the email's content type as one of:
Content-Type: multipart/mixed
Content-Type: multipart/related
Content-Type: multipart/alternative

I understand that multipart/alternative is used for example for HTML emails which include a plain-text conversion.
But I don't know what the two other types signify. It is explained in RDC5621 but I find the definition very badly written and I do not understand it. Could someone please explain to me in simple English what "multipart/mixed" and "multipart/related" refer to and in which situations I have to used them ?

Related:  Mail multipart/alternative vs multipart/mixed

As you say, multipart/alternative is used when the subparts represent different views of the same information.  So, a multipart/alternative will usually contain a text/html and a text/plain, and it's up to the mail reader to decide which one to use.
multipart/mixed just means there are multiple separate subparts within the message.  If you have an HTML message with a PDF attachment to a mail, it would look like:

multipart/mixed

multipart/alternative

text/html
text/plain


application/x-pdf



multipart/related support is optional.  It's basically a multipart/mixed section where the parts inside have some kind of relationship to each other.  Unless there is some specific agreement, it can be treated like multipart/mixed.
